# Refresh DynamoDB credentials after it is expired

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I call the following code to get DynamoDB credentials for my AWS tables.

My problem is that after 1 hour my permission expires and when I recall these routines again it does not refresh my credential and can not access database.

But if I re-start my app it works.

How can I refresh without need to re-start the app?

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                          initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                          identityPoolId:@"us-east-1:*****************"];
    //[credentialsProvider refresh];
    //[AWSServiceManager initialize];
    //[AWSServiceManager dealloc];


    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

 dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
```

Comment: I don't think you need to recall all the code above to re-initialize everything, you simply need to call the "refresh" method of the credentialsProvider in order for the credentials to refresh.

Comment: It seems like it was a bug in DynamoDB and Amazon fixed it. now you do not need to worry about expiration after an hour